# C Question: (const void *) vs (void *)

Tags: c, pointers, constants

What's the difference between `const void *` and `void *`? Under what circumstances can a void pointer be cast to a `const void` pointer?

Answer (score 38):

A `const void *` points to memory that should not be modified.

A `void *` (non-const) points to memory that could be modified (but not via the `void *`; you'd have to cast it first).

When you use `memmove()`, the source address is cast to `const void *`:

```
void *memmove(void *dst, const void *src, size_t nbytes);
```

That is an illustration when a void pointer can be cast to a constant void pointer.  Basically, you can do it (convert to constant) at any time when you know you are not going to modify the memory that the pointer points at.  This applies to any pointer - not just void pointers.

Converting the other way (from a constant pointer to a non-constant pointer) is a much more dangerous exercise.  There's no guarantee that the memory pointed at actually is modifiable; for example, a string literal can be stored in readonly (constant) memory, and if you lose the const-ness with a cast and try to modify the string, you will likely get a segmentation fault or its equivalent - your program will stop suddenly and not under your control.  This is not a good thing.  So, do not change pointers from constant to non-constant without being very sure it is actually OK to lie to your compiler.  Be aware that compilers do not like being lied to and can get their own back, usually at the most inconvenient moment (such as when demonstrating your program to an important prospective client in front of your boss, your boss's boss, and your boss's boss's boss).

Comment: "your boss's boss's boss" - excellent, this might become my new example of undefined behavior. I usually use "catch fire", but now I'm considering "detect how many people are watching and work if it's less than 3", or "work if and only if the code is running under the unit test harness".

Comment: To be more precise  `const void * a` means that this specific pointer cannot modify a data, but pointer to a data can be modified. On the other hand `void * const a` means that pointer is immutable but a data can be modified. void * means that mutable pointer can point to data that can be modified

Comment: For newbies who does not know void pointer in C like me: 1, In C General Purpose Pointer is called as void Pointer; 2, It does not have any data type associated with it; 3, It can store address of any type of variable; 4, A void pointer is a C convention for a raw address

Answer (score 9):

It's perfectly reasonable to cast a `void *` to a `const void *` and the compiler should do so implicitly behind the scenes without any thought on your part, but the other way around is dangerous and must be avoided.

Remember, if a function takes a `const` pointer, then you're free to pass to it either a `const` or a non-`const` value. Saying you take a `const` pointer is just you declaring that the memory won't be modified by your function.

An example: (note that the lines marked *DANGER* should throw a compiler error)

```
const void *p_const;
void *p_buffer;

// const pointers are allowed to hold static memory
p_const = "Foo"; // allowed
p_buffer = "Foo"; // DANGER!!!

// casting to const is implicit
p_const = malloc(LEN); // allowed - implicit cast
p_buffer = malloc(LEN); // allowed

// casting to const implicit again
write(STDOUT, p_const, LEN); // allowed
write(STDOUT, p_buffer, LEN); // also allowed - implicit cast

// const memory cannot be used where mutable memory is expected
read(0, p_buffer, LEN); // allowed
read(0, p_const, LEN); // DANGER!!

// To make the above more obivous, we'll skip the intermediate variable
// and place instead what it holds
read(0, malloc(LEN), LEN); // allowed - useless but at least no crashes
read(0, "foo", 4); // DANGER!!!
```

As a general rule, if a function you write takes in a pointer to a value that you're not going to modify, then the function signature should use a `const` pointer. Using a pointer that isn't declared `const` means that the memory you're pointing to is allowed to be modified.

Another example:

```
void do_something(const void* ptr, int length);

// Since the signature is a const pointer, I know I can call it like this:
do_something("foo",4);
```

Conversely, function calls for a non-constant pointer, then I have to allow for it:

```
void do_something(void* ptr, int length);

// This tells me that the function may overwrite my value.
// The safe solution therefore looks more like this:

char *myptr = char[4];
memcpy(myptr,"foo",4);    
do_something(myptr,4);
```

Similarly, if you ever find yourself in a situation where you need to cast a `const` pointer to a non-`const` one, you should duplicate pointed-to value to a mutable part of memory, and pass your duplicate to the function rather than the original. If that sounds like a headache, that's because it is. If you find yourself in that situation, then you've probably done something wrong.

Conceptually, if the variable holds a "value", then it's likely a `const` pointer. If, instead it holds a "buffer", then it's a non-`const` pointer.

Pointers in you function signatures should **always** be declared `const` unless you intend to write to that memory. Following that rule will help you avoid disastrous problems in your program's logic.

I didn't understand this simple rule until I had been programming for 6 years.