# const void (* to function)

Tags: c++, function-pointers, const-pointer

#### Is there any difference between:

`void (* const algorithm)();`

**and**

`void const (* const algorithm)();`

**when dealing with `const` pointers to static methods?**

I understand that it would make sense to use `const` if the pointer points to memory that should not be modified, in case of pointers to variables, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5547209/2237467). However, are function addresses not effectively constant during run-time anyway?

<sub>The reason I am asking this is, the **second** option as a function parameter does not work.</sub>

**EDIT**

Here is the code that does not compile.

```
struct A {
    static void a() {}
};

void b(void const (* const callback)()) {}

int main() {
    b(&A::a); // No matching function for call to 'b'
}
```

The above example works, if function `a()` has a return type `const void`.

Comment: offtopic: better use a `typedef` or a `using` when dealing with function pointers. I find even the simple ones confusing. Was staring at your declarations for minutes until I gave up :P

Comment: In second, your function returns `const void` which has no sense...

Comment: can you show the code that you say does not work and the error you get? I couldnt reproduce an error when using either of the two

Comment: @user463035818 but never typedef a pointer. Typedef the function type if you want, and use the asterisk on pointers explicitly.

Comment: @user2079303 why that? for function pointers there is not much danger of confusing the two, or do I miss something?

Comment: @user463035818 I have a constructor signature like: `Thing(void const (* const algorithm)() = nullptr);` and if I call it with `Thing(&MyClass::myStaticFunction);` I get a `No matching constructor for initialization of 'Thing'` but if I remove the `const` after the `void`, the error does not occur.

Comment: probably because `myStatusFunction` returns `void` not `const void`

Comment: @user463035818 yeah, but if returning a `const void` makes no sense whatsoever, why does the compiler distinguish between them... I mean, there must be a reason...

Comment: no idea, though the language is compilcated enough so why make a special rule for `const void` when anyhow there is no use for it?

Comment: imho it would have been better if you had included a [mcve] in the question. Somehow the answer (which sounds correct) explains that the error you describe in the comment shouldnt happen (if there really is no difference between `void` and `void const`, then why the error?)

Comment: @user463035818 did now, edited it

Comment: @user463035818 `why that?` primarily because of the same reason why you'd want a typedef in the first place. A typedef of a function pointer is just as hard to read as a variable of function pointer type that doesn't use a typedef. But a typedef of a function type is clear to read, and so is a pointer to such typedef. Besides, it is never a bad idea to clearly see that what you have is a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` after (or before) the return type applies to the return type. There is no such thing as a "pointer to const function" as there is no such thing as a const function. <sub>(Although, there is such thing as a pointer to const member function, as const member functions do exist. But there the constness applies to the object argument, not to the function itself. There the constness is expressed in the same way as in the declaration of a member function - after the parenthesized parameter list)</sub>.

There is no difference between `void()` and `void const()` in the sense that both functions behave exactly the same because there is no behavioral difference between a const void return type and a non-const void return type. Object cannot be const when there is no object.

I would expect a compiler to issue a warning when a non-class return value is directly qualified with const.

However, `void()` and `void const()` are different in the sense that `void` and `void const` are technically separate types, as are all const qualified types different from their non-const counterpart. Therefore the function pointers to const returning and non-const returning functions are different function pointer types. As such, the standard won't allow a function pointer to one type be bound to a function of another type.

So, to fix your non-compiling code, simply replace `void const` which is nonsensical with `void` in the function pointer.

Comment: Unless you mean *__void__ return __type__* instead of *return __value__* this answer is very confusing and potentially misleading.

Comment: @anddero you cannot modify a function through a function pointer whether it is `const` or not

Comment: @user463035818 tru, EDIT: but u sure?

Comment: @anddero when its about c++ i am never 100% sure about anything

Comment: @anddero OK, my answer was a bit overreaching. const return type can make a difference when returning a class type. It does not make a difference when returning a fundamental type, and particularly not when nothing is returned. I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the "inner" `const` :

```
using void_function = void();
void (*p1)() = nullptr;        // similar to `void_function* p1 = nullptr;`
void (* const p2)() = nullptr; // similar to `void_function* const p2 = nullptr;`
```

`p2` is `constant` whereas `p1` is mutable.

When moving `const`, as following:

```
const void_function* p3 = nullptr; // or void_function const* p3; // -> const has no effect
void (const* p4)() = nullptr;      // Invalid syntax
```

There are no "`const` function" vs "mutable function".

Now, looking at function return type:

Types `void ()` (function returning `void`) and `const void ()` (function returning `const void` !?) are different.

Even if `const void` make no real sense, it is a valid type.

It might make sense to return `const` object from function to disallow "direct" modification of the object:

```
const std::string make_const_string();

make_const_string().push_back('*'); // Doesn't work
std::string s = make_const_string(); // OK, create mutable copy.
```

So to fix your code:

```
struct A {
    static void a() {}
};

void b(void const (* const callback)()) {}

int main() {
    b(&A::a); // No matching function for call to 'b'
}
```

You have to make `&A::a` match `b`'s argument type:

- `static const void a() {}`
- `void b(void (*const callback)())`

I suggest second one as `const void` make no real sense.